# Python SSH Session with User/Password Login

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

for my work i want to connect to serveral routers and configure them over SSH.
I try to do something in Python.
On Google i found serveral Tutorials for Paramiko or something else but i am not able to connect to the devices.
The routers are not in my Hand and the only to connect is username/password login.
Manual login over PuTTy works fine. But on unknown reasons the scripted login with Paramiko or PLINK.exe (with username and password parameter) is it not working.

Python Example for SSH Session:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
if ssh.get_transport() is not None:
  print("Connected")
else:
 print("Not Connected")
```

With this simple Snippet following Error is shown:

```
Error:
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

It looks like the password is not used.

I am wondering if there any way to establish an SSH connection with Python where the password send delayed via stdin?

Thx in advance,
Marcus

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your code for making an ssh connection to the router. Explain what happens when you run it. Include any error messages that you get.

Comment: I have edit my post

Comment: Has anyone an Idea????